# Future prediction using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, time-series, prediction, tensor

I am new to TensorFlow. I like to learn more about time series model and future prediction.

For example, I have a data set year ranges from 2010 to 2018. Using this data, I need to predict the future values such as how the values will be in 2019 or 2020. (without passing any test data set)

Whether it is possible to achieve using TensorFlow. If so please share a sample and documentation so that it will help me to learn more.

Comment: Have you searched "time series analysis tensorflow" in your favorite search engine to see what pops up?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Time Series Forecasting example given below.
https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/text/time_series
See Part 1 for univariate time series forecasting
and Part 2 for multivariate time series forecasting.
Hope this helps you to get started.